# sailsjs where many to many relationship contains

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

Im trying to find all users that are doing a certain subject. Here is the relationship:

**User.js**

```
attributes: {
    subjects: { collection: 'subject', via: 'users', dominant: true }, // Many to Many
    levels: { collection: 'level', via: 'users', dominant: true } // Many to Many
}
```

**Subject.js**

```
attributes: {
    users : { collection: 'user', via: 'subjects' } // Many to Many
}
```

**Level.js**

```
attributes: {
    users : { collection: 'user', via: 'levels' } // Many to Many
}
```

I would like to be able to do a find on User and only return users that have a relationship to a specific subject. Something like this:

```
User.find({ subjects: { 'contains': 1 } })
  .exec(function(err, results){
      if(err) return res.serverError(err);
      users = results;

      return res.json(users);
  });
```

I know that I can do it by doing:

```
Subject.findOne({id:1})
  .populate('users')
  .exec(function(err, results){
      if(err) return res.serverError(err);
      users = results.users;

      return res.json(users);
  });
```

However I do not want to do it this way as I may want to filter by more than just subject. For example using the above I may want to find all users that are doing subject 1 **AND** are doing level 2.

```
User.find({ subjects: { 'contains': 1 }, levels: { 'contains': 2 } })
  .exec(function(err, results){
      if(err) return res.serverError(err);
      users = results;

      return res.json(users);
  });
```

I am using sails v0.12.3

Answer (score 1):

There is no such mechanism as far as I know where you can search as you mentioned.

Though you can do it in following ways:

1. Using condition in `populate`

   ```
    User.find()
     .populate('subjects', {
       name: 'subject-1'
     })
     .populate('levels', {
       name: 'level-1'
     })
     .exec(function(err, user) {
       if (err) {
         // Error
       }
       sails.log.verbose(user);
     });
   ```
2. Using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

   ```
   async.auto({
     subject: function(cb) {
       Subject.findOne({
           name: 'subject-1'
         })
         .exec(cb);
     },
     level: function(cb) {
       Level.findOne({
           name: 'level-1'
         })
         .exec(cb);
     },
     user: ['subject', 'level', function(cb, results) {
       User.find({
           subjects: results.subject.id,
           levels: results.level.id
         })
         .exec(function(err, users) {
           if (err) {
             return cb(err);
           }
           sails.log.verbose(users); // Required user
         });
     }]
   }, function(err, results) {
     // Callback
   });
   ```
3. Using [.query() method](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query) where you have to write a `JOIN` query to fetch data.

Comment: Example 1 does not do what I would like it to, it finds all users then filters the subjects and levels for each user. It does not return all users that are attached to the selected subjects/levels.

The second example looks to be doing the same as the first and therefore is still not doing what we need it to do.

We could do it using a .query() but I would like to do it without using a native query.

Comment: I am not sure about the first one but second one should work just fine

Comment: I need a list of users in both the level passed in and the subject passed in not just one user as your code provides.

Comment: I have edited the code to give you a list of users whose subject name is subject-1 and level is level-1.

Comment: I have tried your code. This does not return what I need. the "users" variable returns undefined and the "results" variable returns the level and the subject specified but no users.

Comment: Can you please check if there is any user with both the values? Also try logging 'err' variable.

Comment: Error says Unknown column 'user.subjects' in 'where clause'. This is because it is a many to many relationship so it has a join table.